# Accessing GCP Memorystore from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

Is this possible? all cloud functions are running in `us-central1`, Memorystore is running in `us-central1-f` but with an internal IP: `10.0.0.3`

I saw the docs such as https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/samples , no instruction for connecting from cloud function at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

We currently [don't support access from Cloud Functions to Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#connecting). This is something we are working on.

Comment: is it possible for you to share an approximate ETA for CF access to Cloud MS? Also, what's Google's recommended workaround to overcome this? Redis on GCE?

Comment: So that's why I couldn't get it to connect. Any alternatives aside from running our own VM?

Comment: The current ETA for supporting access from CF is Q2. We are looking at having an alpha release in Q1, I will update this thread once we have a concrete date.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use Serverless VPC Access to connect from Cloud Functions to Cloud Memorystore. Here's the documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access